# PHP !isset & empty & session check turning true every time

Tags: php, session, isset, is-empty

Seems silly but really  confused me.
Every refresh takes me inside this condition.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
echo "Session turned on";
}
```

I tried changing the condition to `if(empty($_SESSION))` and 
`if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)` but still every time it the statements inside are getting executed.

I am Trying to increment the counter

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
echo "Session turned on";
}

$current_time=date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
echo $current_time;
if(!isset($_SESSION["counter"]["time"]))
{
    $_SESSION["counter"]["time"]=date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
    increamentCounter();
}
$diff = abs(strtotime($current_time) - strtotime($_SESSION["counter"]["time"]));
$time_in_minutes=$diff/60;
if($time_in_minutes>30)
{
    unset($_SESSION["counter"]["time"]);
}
echo $time_in_minutes."<br>";
function increamentCounter()
{
    $pre_counter_value = file_get_contents("counter.txt");
    $counter_value = (int)$pre_counter_value+1;
    file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter_value);
}
echo file_get_contents("counter.txt");
?>
```

Comment: sessions are usually used for multiple pages. If this isn't being passed to subsequent pages, you should edit your post to include the code for it.

Comment: *"Every refresh takes me inside this condition"* - Right; the session is never set, so your posted code did just that; its job. We don't know where you're setting a session array/value anywhere.

Comment: @C0dekid  I have followed that answer  before questioning here & that doesn't work for me !

Comment: well every answer given below is what's posted in that possible duplicate, I also asked for clarification; I got back nothing. So take it up with them.

Comment: That is only one single page.. i am trying with session.

Comment: @VardhamanJain Can you please post the complete code so that we will know what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for a session variable before calling `session_start()`, as a result your if condition will always return true. Try:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    echo "Session detected";
} else {
    echo "No session";
}
```